# Django-filter filtering by reverse foreignkey

Tags: django, django-filter

I have a 3 models: Product, Action, ActionProduct.

```
class Product (models.Model):
     p = models.CharField()

class Action(models.Model):
     a = ... 
     <a lot more fields>
    
class ActionProduct(models.Model):
    product = ForeignKey(ProductList)
    action = ForeignKey(Action)
```

**My goal is to be able to filter Action model by product.**

It works great with other fields and Foreign keys, like category, author, etc:

```
category = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    queryset=CategorySocial.objects.all() 
)
```

**But how do I filter by reverse foreign key?**

Challenge comes when using django-filters and want to filter Action model by product.
I tried to rearrange by filtering ActionProduct model. It almost works. But product model was added recently, and not all actions has Product chosen, so actions without product is lost.

Could you guide me to some direction?

Comment: Is `ActionProduct` not a `through` model of a `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: I started thinking that i might chose a wrong field. Never used ManyToMany before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `ManyToManyField` would simply implicitly make a model similar to the `ActionProduct` model you have made. Since you have already made this model simply specify it as the [`through` model [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) for the `ManyToManyField`. This way you can make queries easier and you can then filter easily:

```py
class Action(models.Model):
     a = ... 
     products = models.ManyToManyField(
         Product,
         through='ActionProduct',
         related_name='actions'
     )
     <a lot more fields>
```

Now run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` so that your migration files reflect this.

Now in your filterset you can simply add `products` as a `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` as it is a field on your model:

```py
products = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
    queryset=Product.objects.all() 
)
```

Or simply add it to `fields` attribute in `Meta` of the filterset:

```py
class SomeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Action
        fields = ['products', ...]
```

Comment: That is a great explanation. Thank you. I was already implementing ManyToMany field but was not aware of 'through'. Will read a more about it. Any way, thanks!